# Is there a way to tell if a POST (body) request is formatted as a URL encoded query string or JSON data?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express, urlencode

I am writing the server side code to handle incoming post requests (using NodeJS and Express).

If the request coming into the server is formatted as JSON data, then I want to use JSON.parse, but if the data coming in is formatted as a URL encoded query string, then using JSON.parse on that data gives me the error below. Any suggestions? Code at the bottom.

[image]

```
app.post("/", (req, res) => {
    
    let parsedData;
   
    // if request.body is received as JSON data, I want to put it inside the loop below and parse it and then set parsedData equal to that parsed data.
    // if the request.body is received as url encoded data, I just want to set parsedData = req.body
    for (var key in req.body) {
            parsedData = JSON.parse(key);
        }
        
    
})
```

Comment: Did you try to use `body-parser` along with express?

Comment: Yes I already had these at the top of my file:  

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

Comment: Check if a request body corresponds to a content type on client side.

Comment: It's hard to tell what this question is about. "Unexpected token o" typically signals that one is trying to parse an object rather than a string (since `JSON.parse` will call `toString` on the object and get `[object Object]` and choke on the first `o` of `object`), and the image of that text is what takes up half of your question. The other half is code (thankfully text) that tries to parse JSON from the key of a key/value pair, which is odd.

Comment: Can you show what is in `req.body` by outputting it to console?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I was able to figure it out! Basically I created a separate function to see if I could JSON PARSE the req.body

```
function isJSONObject(value) {
    try {
        JSON.parse(value)
    } catch {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Instead of parsing and failing, just use the `Content-Type` header in the request to see what data the client sent